# Как найти строку по регулярному выражению?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
string = '"isSubAgent":false,"phoneNumbers":[{"countryCode":"+7","number":"9098000032"'
y = re.match(r'"isSubAgent":(?:true|false),"phoneNumbers":\[\{"countryCode":"+7",\"number\":"(\d+)"',string)
```

Мне нужно найти эту строку и вывести значение number. У меня не получается и выводит None.

Comment: `+` => `\+`. Это специальный символ.

Comment: `re.search(r'"number":"(\d+)"', string)[1]`. Если у вас номер - всегда последний в строке после двоеточия, то вообще можно без регулярок обойтись.